# Why my POST return [object Object]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in Angular js and I don't know if my POST is working. It returns an [object Object]! What kind of error this? I mean if POST is working is there something wrong with the form?

```
//Activity controller
.controller('ActivityCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $ionicLoading, $ionicScrollDelegate, PostService, $http, AuthService) {
    var user = AuthService.getUser();
    $http.get("http://hannation.me/api/buddypressread/activity_get_activities_grouped/?userid=" + user.data.id)
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.activities = data.activities;
    });



  $scope.addActivity = function(){    
    //    
    var dataObj = {
        new_activity : $scope.new_activity
    };  
    $http.post('http://hannation.me/api/userplus/activities_post_update/?key=57f211a0354d7&cookie=' 
      + user.cookie + '&content=' + dataObj).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.message = data;
    });

    $scope.new_activity='';
  };
})
```

```html
 <form  class="row">
      <div class="col col-80 content col-center">
        <input class="new-comment-message" type="text" placeholder="Leave a comment..." ng-model="new_activity"
         name="new_activity"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-20 button-container col-center">
        <button class="button button-clear send" type="submit" ng-click="addActivity()">
          Send
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You're concatenating `dataObj` in the URL.  You shouldn't concatenate any arbitrary data into the URL.  At a minimum, you need to use `encodeURIComponent()` around your strings like `user.data.id`, but you definitely can't just use `dataObj` as-is.

Comment: @Brad Can you show me some work example for POST?

Comment: snippet is not working..

Comment: @Chetan yes because it code example

Comment: The response of data is an object and you need to look into the object to se what it contains. To do that, In your post success callback method, add: console.log(data); Then press F12 and view the object in the console.

Comment: agree with @MarcusH e.g, like you have done in get request   $scope.activities = data.activities; try to find out the data you want like $scope.message = data.message;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, and mainly because this really bugs me... use the `params` property for query parameters and don't use the [deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice) `success` method. Using `params` ensures your query parameters are sanitised for use in a URL (see [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)).

```
$http.get('http://hannation.me/api/buddypressread/activity_get_activities_grouped/', {
    params: { userid: user.data.id }
}).then(function(response) {
    $scope.activities = response.data.activities;
});
```

Secondly, this [documentation](http://www.parorrey.com/documentation/activities_post_update/) (which I assume is correct) indicates you should be using a `GET` request, not `POST` and `content` appears to be a string so your second request should look like

```
$http.get('http://hannation.me/api/userplus/activities_post_update/', {
    params: {
        key: '57f211a0354d7',
        cookie: user.cookie,
        content: $scope.new_activity
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    // not sure about this, the documentation doesn't indicate there's a response
    console.log('response data', response.data);
});
```

Comment: It was kind working
This error i this content cant added to request

ionic.bundle.js:23826 GET http://hannation.me/api/userplus/activities_post_update/?cookie=adminara%7C…4c1bdc98bd601cbb37b37f1a5cdd2f658d5de39b329fda087e3798e8&key=57f211a0354d7 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @SebastianLagua Happy to help, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score -1):

Answer lie within your question. You are signing object to your message you should do like this

```
 $http.post('http://hannation.me/api/userplus/activities_post_update/?key=57f211a0354d7&cookie=' 
  + user.cookie + '&content=' + dataObj).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.message = data.message;
});
```

Here i have assigned one of the value that i am getting from post request. To know what are the values lie within your response object, console your response object and assign appropriate value to your $scope.message.

Comment: How do you know there's a `message` property in the response?

Comment: i have just given example @Phil